# cannot find azure VM A3-standard pricing

Tags: azure

I want to find out the pricing for A3 Standard VM running RHEL in "US West 2 " in Azure portal . I cannot locate anywhere . Only in the calculator when I input all the details , I can find the price . Anybody can give some input here?

Azure portal pricing page gives only pricing for A3 - Basic .. This gives an impression that A3-standard does not exit . However in the calculator, you can input A3-standard .. How come this discrepancy ??

Thanks,

Chitta

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pricing question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The monthly costs: $194.928.

Link Below:

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/RedHat.RHEL_7?tab=PlansAndPrice

Edit:

Remember when you provision the RHEL VM from Marketplace comes with a monthly license costs. You can buy a license (for production) or get one free (Dev) which would cheaper in the long run.